# Unable to enable Javafx on Eclipse in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: javafx

I recently shifted from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. I have installed eclipse version 2018-09 . The java version that I am using is 1.8.0_191. I am trying to work on a project that makes use of Javafx. I installed Javafx using the instructions available at following [link](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-ambitious). After all the installation is complete and I have restarted eclipse I import the project. I am getting the following error:

> the import javafx cannot be resovled

I have tried setting the build path but still I am getting the same error. Going over one of the stack overflow posts I have tried installing openjfx but still I am getting the same error.

Please any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx
```

And restart Eclipse